# Grouper name `datetime` not found after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this Pandas dataframe

```
        datetime       machineID    errorID
0   2015-01-06 03:00:00     1   error3
1   2015-02-03 06:00:00     1   error4
2   2015-02-21 11:00:00     1   error1
3   2015-02-21 16:00:00     1   error2
4   2015-03-20 06:00:00     1   error1
5   2015-04-04 06:00:00     1   error5
6   2015-05-04 06:00:00     1   error4
7   2015-05-19 06:00:00     1   error2
8   2015-05-19 06:00:00     1   error3
9   2015-06-03 06:00:00     1   error5
```

Now I want to unstack the errorID so that I can get columns based on `error1`, `error2`...`error5`. So for this I have used groupby and unstack method in Pandas

```
a = errors.groupby(['machineID', 'datetime', 'errorID']).size().unstack('errorID', fill_value=0)
```

which gives me this dataframe

```
             errorID    error1  error2  error3  error4  error5
machineID   datetime                    
1   2015-01-06 03:00:00     0   0   1   0   0
    2015-02-03 06:00:00     0   0   0   1   0
    2015-02-21 11:00:00     1   0   0   0   0
    2015-02-21 16:00:00     0   1   0   0   0
    2015-03-20 06:00:00     1   0   0   0   0
```

Now I want to resample this data based on `24H` frequency and on `datetime`. But when I use the `resample` function, it is giving me the error `KeyError: 'The grouper name datetime is not found'`

```
a.resample('24H', on='datetime').agg({'error1':'mean','error2':'mean','error3':'mean','error4':'mean', 'error5':'mean'}).rename(columns={'error1':'error1_mean','error2' : 'error2_mean', 'error3': 'error3_mean', 'error4': 'error4_24mean','error5': 'error5_24mean'})
```

When I listed all the columns in this dataframe, it shows only `['error1', 'error2', 'error3', 'error4', 'error5']`

This is the entire error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-607c418305a0> in <module>
----> 1 a.resample('24H', on='datetime').agg({'error1':'mean','error2':'mean','error3':'mean','error4':'mean', 'error5':'mean'}).rename(columns={'error1':'error1_mean','error2' : 'error2_mean', 'error3': 'error3_mean', 'error4': 'error4_24mean','error5': 'error5_24mean'})

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base, on, level)
   8447             base=base,
   8448             key=on,
-> 8449             level=level,
   8450         )
   8451         return _maybe_process_deprecations(

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in resample(obj, kind, **kwds)
   1304     """
   1305     tg = TimeGrouper(**kwds)
-> 1306     return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
   1307 
   1308 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in _get_resampler(self, obj, kind)
   1428 
   1429         """
-> 1430         self._set_grouper(obj)
   1431 
   1432         ax = self.ax

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in _set_grouper(self, obj, sort)
    171             else:
    172                 if key not in obj._info_axis:
--> 173                     raise KeyError("The grouper name {0} is not found".format(key))
    174                 ax = Index(obj[key], name=key)
    175 

KeyError: 'The grouper name datetime is not found'
```

I don't how do I use resample after groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert values to datetimes:

```
errors['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(errors['datetime'])

a = errors.groupby(['machineID', 'datetime', 'errorID']).size().unstack('errorID', fill_value=0)
```

Then if need `resample` per `machineID` use:

```
a = a.reset_index(level=0).groupby('machineID').resample('24H').agg({'error1':'mean','error2':'mean','error3':'mean','error4':'mean', 'error5':'mean'}).rename(columns={'error1':'error1_mean','error2' : 'error2_mean', 'error3': 'error3_mean', 'error4': 'error4_24mean','error5': 'error5_24mean'})
```

Or if need only `resample` use:

```
a = a.reset_index(level=0).resample('24H').agg({'error1':'mean','error2':'mean','error3':'mean','error4':'mean', 'error5':'mean'}).rename(columns={'error1':'error1_mean','error2' : 'error2_mean', 'error3': 'error3_mean', 'error4': 'error4_24mean','error5': 'error5_24mean'})
```

Or if need groupby with `Grouper` use:

```
a = a.groupby(['machineID', pd.Grouper(freq='24H', level='datetime')]).agg({'error1':'mean','error2':'mean','error3':'mean','error4':'mean', 'error5':'mean'}).rename(columns={'error1':'error1_mean','error2' : 'error2_mean', 'error3': 'error3_mean', 'error4': 'error4_24mean','error5': 'error5_24mean'})
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be- `a = errors.reset_index(level=0).resample('24H').agg({'error1':'mean','error2':'mean','error3':'mean','error4':'mean', 'error5':'mean'}).rename(columns={'error1':'error1_mean','error2' : 'error2_mean', 'error3': 'error3_mean', 'error4': 'error4_24mean','error5': 'error5_24mean'})`

Comment: Also for both of them it is giving this error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar - Answer was edited.

Comment: @jexrael the code snippet gives mean for just 1 machineID. What if I want for all the machineIDs which are 1-1000?

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar - last solution from answer working?

Comment: Yeah, worked. Thanks!